# .Net equivalent of VB6 Recordset

Tags: .net

I want to know the equivalent of vb recordset in .net?

Which ado.net object can be used to replace vb recordset?

Comment: I simply want to achieve same functionalities as recordset have in .net, how to do this?

Comment: Which one ado.net object meet the closest functionality to recordset?

Comment: what is the LockEnumType property of recordset replacement in .net?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct replacement in ADO.NET for a VB6 recordset. It depends what you want to use it for, but candidates are

- a [Dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zb0sdh0b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (this is probably the closest match)
- a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zd7cwzh.aspx)
- or a [DataReader](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/should-you-use-ado.net-datareader-or-dataset/)

A very basic example would be:

```
    public DataSet GetDataset(string sql, string connectionString)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlConn))
            {
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

You should also take a look at:

- [Comparison of ADO.NET and ADO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/904fck4k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [Generating Strongly Typed DataSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wha85tzb.aspx)
- [Linq2Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)

Comment: i want to replace lockTypeEnum in .net?